# Vaadin access content of sql container

Tags: java, parsing, vaadin

EDITED!

I retriev data from a mysql DB using Vaadin, SQLContainer and the Freeformquery. Now I want to get all Descriptions in one String (later each string will printed/added to a text file).

```
....
String text ="";
FreeformQuery subcatExtractionQuery = new FreeformQuery("select Description from customers", connectionPool);
SQLConateiner s = new SQLContainer(subcatExtractionQuery);

Collection<?> c = s.getContainerPropertyIds();
    for(Object o : c){
        Property<?> p = s.getContainerProperty(o, "Description");
        text+=(String)p.getValue();
    }
    System.out.println(text);
```

I get the Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Problem line is the text+=...if I remove it, no error appears. BUT The Query returns Data!

These descriptions are Strings. I need to have all words of each string in ony single list of tokens (i already have a method to create a token list of a file.)
(Don't ask if this makes sense, it's just an example).

How can I access the Strings of my sql container? Till now I only used the container als data source of a table and didn't access the single items/strings.
I need a for loop to get each String...how does this work?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve, because this sound more suited for a basic JDBC/ORM query without any other Vaadin interaction, except maybe for a button click... Are you trying to save the data you're showing in a table/grid/etc to a file or..? Please provide some more details.

Comment: You can retrieve all ItemId from the container (which identify the rows) and then with getItemProperty(..) retrieve the value of the field(s)

Comment: I treid this:    FreeformQuery subcatExtractionQuery = new FreeformQuery("select Message from "+sqlPart, connectionPool);
   SQLContainer s = new SQLContainer(subcatExtractionQuery); But this does not work
   Collection t = s.getContainerPropertyIds();
   for(Object o : t){
    o.getItemProperty();
   }

Answer (score 0):

Its getItemIds insted of getContainerPropertyIds. So this words

```
....
String text ="";
FreeformQuery subcatExtractionQuery = new FreeformQuery("select Description from customers", connectionPool);
SQLConateiner s = new SQLContainer(subcatExtractionQuery);

Collection<?> c = s.getItemIds();
for(Object o : c){
    Property<?> p = s.getContainerProperty(o, "Description");
    text+=(String)p.getValue();
}
System.out.println(text);
```